# Generating autosorted HTML tables from text file?

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

**Update**

I managed to get my table generated using [gabel's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667816/generating-autosorted-html-tables-from-text-file/4667994#4667994) suggestion with a few minor issues.

This was especially useful since my colleague only has to edit a .CSV file in Excel.

Due to presentation reasons, she now wants the table to look like so:

```
------------------------------
| FRUITS       | VEGGIES     |
------------------------------
| Banana       | Potato      |
------------------------------
| Cherry       | Pumpkin     |
------------------------------
| Orange       | Okra        |
------------------------------
| MEATS        | CARBS       |
------------------------------
| Chicken      | Bread       |
------------------------------
| Beef         | Rice        |
------------------------------
| Pork         |             |
------------------------------
```

There are two `thead` entries or perhaps two tables but the .CSV file would still be:

```
FRUITS,VEGGIES,MEATS,CARBS
Banana,Potato,Chicken,Bread
...
```

**Questions**

1. How would I parse the CSV file that it would break after the second comma and then create a new table or a new header/body set within the same table?

---

There's a HTML table I'd like to have generated with as little work possible for the person actually filling in the data.

The table looks like this (proxy example):

```
------------------------------
| FRUITS       | VEGGIES     |
------------------------------
| Banana       | Potato      |
------------------------------
| Cherry       | Pumpkin     |
------------------------------
| Orange       | Okra        |
------------------------------
```

Currently, the table is done in standard HTML and I'm using CSS and jQuery to give it specific colours and 'zebra'-striping, respectively. The alphabetical sorting has been done manually.

However, with the code set in place the person I'm handing it over to does not want to edit the HTML. She'd rather edit some text file where she can write/edit (this was just a suggestion from a friend):

```
{Banana: Fruit, Potato: Veggies, Okra: Veggies... }
```

The Javascript should then pick up this source file, generate a table where the individual columns are automatically sorted alphabetically and then zebra-striped using the CSS layout.

**Questions**

1. I've got the jQuery plug-in. What else would I need to actually generate the tables?
2. Would you recommend using the above dictionary structure for the source file or perhaps a CSV file?
3. For the sake of argument, happens when I face the scenario of `{Tomato: Fruit, Tomato: Veggies...}`. Is there a workaround for this case?

This may seem like overkill, but it's something I need to get done.

Comment: IMO, it makes more sense to use a server-side language to generate the table. Do you have one available?

Comment: Do you have PHP or ASP.NET [etc.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting#Examples) available?

Comment: This table is being used in SharePoint. It's a web part where I can do some HTML but I'm not sure I can use those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could checkout the following jQueryPlugin which reads in a csv File and creates a table. And csv's can be exported by MS Excel from any <strike>fool</strike> normal user...

http://code.google.com/p/jquerycsvtotable/

Comment: Does it just output a table automatically? Or is there something I can apply the CSS, striping and sorting to?

Comment: It triggers an event on table creation, after that you can apply all other JS stuff.

Comment: Gotcha. If I wanted to make the .CSV like so: `header 1, element 1, element 2` as opposed to `header 1, header 2` - how would I do that? The documentation is kind of non-existent.

Comment: Why would you like to do so? And even if it's neccessary you can easily transpose rows & cols with the tool you edit the table source file. I thought it the other user should be able to edit that table in a pretty easy way, if (he/she) even does not know how to write HTML Code.

Comment: True, true. Also, if I had to have two tables like the one above, with one on top of the other (for formatting purposes, I can't fit a four-column table -- so it needs to be a two-col table followed by a two-col table), can I generate the tables from the same .CSV file?

Comment: Phew - that's a good question. I'm pretty sure it's way easier working with two csvs for two tables.

Comment: Hehe, my friend suggested the same thing. It's probably swishier to work with one but the chances of it breaking just go up! I'll try out the two CSV -> two table strategy first...

Comment: Hiya, the two-table strategy is having some issues. Okay, say I've created two placeholders: `<div id=fruits_and_veg></div>` and `<div id=meats_and_carbs></div>`. Now the CSS file has all the table presentation as `#fruits_and_veg`. The `meats_and_carbs` table would use the same CSS. If I use it under the fruits_and_veg name, it doesn't work (id's don't match). Do I have to recreate the CSS under meats_and_carbs?

Comment: You can define the CSS with #fruits_and_veg, #meats_and_carbs { style: attr; } OR better you could use a class attribute for both table in your CSS.  <table id="veggy" class="stylishtable"></table><table id="meatlove" class="stylishtable"></table>  and in the css you use table.stylishtable instead of #fruits_and_veg

Comment: Ah brilliant! One more question would be: all the elements in that table... how can I add links (i.e. `a href`) to them?

Comment: Just a hint in the probably right direction jQuery('table.stylishtable td').each(function () { jQuery(this).html().wrap("<a href='http://domain.tld/?id=' />")  });

Comment: What's this code doing here? I get that we're searching for any table that's of class stylishtable and for all the td's (so this should exclude the thead's which is ideal) it... and that's where I lose the plot.

Comment: Hmmm, let me take a further guess... this will add an `a href` wrapper to each element. And then I can use some more jQuery to modify the links for each specific food item?

Comment: Re: your post about defining the CSS with #fruits_and_veg... I tried the second option but it didn't work. It couldn't pick up on what I wanted so I'm still kinda stuck with `#fruits_and_veg tabe, #meat_and_carbs table {...}`. I tried `table.stylishtable {...}` and renamed my CSVToTable to `<div id="fruits_and_veg class="stylishtable"></div>` but it just broke and lost all formatting.

Comment: that should work this way - but I don't know the exact css/js code you're using... a jsfiddle would be nice to see it in live action.

Comment: Ah I think the issue was literally doing what you said (`table.stylishtable`)! Whoops! I thought about it a bit and did `div.stylishtable` (because CSVToTable uses `div` to place the table) and it all worked. Good, that abstracts the thing a bit more. If I can figure out how to do the `a href` wrapping now I'll be over the moon :). What do you mean by jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gabel/SYcYg/ just see by yourself ;) a picture is worth a thousand words..

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer since it dealt with my main query. I'll use this thread should I need further help. Can't thank you enough! :)

Comment: Nvm mate, thats what stackoverflow was made for. Thx for accepting it anyway

Answer (score 2):

For easy table building with jQuery, I suggest  [jQuery DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/). It have sorting functionality built-in, plus filtering, zebra coloring, paging, and so on.

You can use its API to retrieve the JSON data and build the table automatically: [AJAX example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html).

Comment: Can it pull in a .CSV file? I'm having a bit of trouble with CSVToTable (below) so I was wondering if DataTables can solve my problem?  
  
Also, can you sort columns independently of each other?

Comment: Out of the box, I guess it does not parse CSV, but you can easily obtain the file, split each line and turn it into array data for input, for example. You can code it in five minutes :)  See the examples for a quick overview of the features available. And yes, you can sort each column independently (try the table on the main page).

Answer (score 0):

You're fine with jQuery. The zebra-striping can easily be achieved using CSS:

```
#the_table_id tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
#the_table_id tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

(Sorry if you knew that already, couldn't really tell from your post)

Concerning the data: If you can manage to get *"the other guy"* to write JSON, you get off easy.

```
var data = {
  "Banana": "Potatoe",
  "Tomatoe": "Banana",
  //...
  "Something": "else"
}
```

Now use jQuery to traverse that map, sort it with jQuery and put it into the table. As a reference, see [this](http://www.onemoretake.com/2009/02/25/sorting-elements-with-jquery/).
As you can see, you can write your own comparison function, so you can handle your special case (case #3 in your post) in any way you like.

#### Edit:

Okay, so it's not quite as straight forward as I imagined it to be - but, well see for yourself:
Here's an example of how this could work. `data` is in here for convenience. It could be sourced out in to a separate file and be included via `<script src=...>` as mentioned above.

```
  var data = {
    "Banana": "Position 2",
    "Apple": "Position 1",
    "Cherry": "Position 3"
  };

  var keys = Array();

  $(function() {
    // Extract keys for sorting
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
      keys.push(index);
    });
    // Sort keys
    keys.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a > b;
    });
    // Traverse sorted keys and put data into table
    $.each(keys, function(index, item) {
      $("#the_table").append("<tr><td>"+item+"</td><td>"+data[item]+"</td></tr>");
    });
  });
```

This assumes, you have an (probably empty) table with id `the_table` in your document.

Comment: I've already got the zebra striping working. It's the table generation and autosorting that's stumping me.

Comment: Also, could you explain a bit more about the JSON bit?

Comment: Take a look at the [page I referenced already](http://www.onemoretake.com/2009/02/25/sorting-elements-with-jquery/). You basically include the data from the other guy with `<script src=...>`, sort the data via `$(data).sort(func(){...})` (again, see link), and put it into the table with `$(data).each(...)`

Comment: I'll be honest: that page doesn't make much sense to me. I'm a novice at this stuff.

Comment: So if that is a JSON file (does that even make sense), is it stored as, say, `fruits.json` or just as a `.txt` file?

Comment: That really doesn't matter. Call it `data.js`, call it `badgerbadgerbadger.data`, as long as you include it in a script-tag, it will be interpreted as JavaScript. To clarify, the *"JSON-File"* consists only of `var data = { /*data*/ };`